# Is “are of very” grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

I am writing this in the context of writing to a university:

> The [name] university is well known in the scientific community and its courses **are of very** respected academic value.

I would like to know if the construct “are of very” is grammatically correct.

Comment: What would you like to know?

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung the `are of very` is correct gramatically or not?

Comment: Yes. It says the courses are of value—what kind of value? Very respected academic value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not “are of very” but “are of [adjective] [noun]” where [adjective] is the adjectival phrase “very respected” and [noun] is the noun phrase “academic value”. The construction “X is of [adjective] [noun]” means “the [noun] of X is [adjective]” and can be used for nouns expressing qualities with an adjective quantifying the quality. It is also possible to directly qualify the noun: “an X of [adjective] [noun]”.

> This topic is of great importance.
>   This woman is of considerable means.
>   I see a man of average height.
>   He is a man of little faith.

Comment: i will say depending of my understanding to your answer. first you implied that my sentence means that "the academic value of the courses are very respected " right? Also, from you asnwer can i implied that "its courses are of respected academic value" the correct one?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Yes, or rather “the academic value of the courses **is** very respected” (by the way, *highly* would be more idiomatic than *very* here).

Comment: "idionmatic" means more bad or more good pleaes?

Comment: Also why you said the academic value of `the` courses. and not the academic value of `its` courses please?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli [idiomatic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/idiomatic) ≈ “something a native speaker would say”. Hmm, yes, I can see that the Wiktionary definitions is not helpful. [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+idiomatic) finds a better one.

Comment: so it is more better to native speaker :)

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Unlike "more better", which is something a native speaker would not say :-)  Just "better" will do.

Comment: @snailplane i didn't understand your comment, please tell me explicity. should i use very or hhighly ?

Comment: I don't really see an answer here. Is your answer "yes"? The example sentence is pretty awkward, even if you can make the argument for a grammatical structure.

Comment: @DCShannon The answer isn't “yes” or “no” because either would be misleading. The sentence is valid but the sequence of words that the question highlights is not a standalone phrase.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to stretch the rules of grammar to allow that sentence construction, but it's very awkward and sounds wrong.

It sounds to me like you're trying to say that

> The [name] university is well known in the scientific community and its courses are very respected for their academic value.

Besides some set phrases, like "a man of average height", it's probably best to avoid this construction.